# Google Content API for Shopping not adding all products

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, extensions, google-api

So, I've recently switched a Magento store from using XML feeds to using the Google Content API. I've installed the [official Magento extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html) which is being used to feed the API.

Almost all products have been added succesfully. I'm left with 35 products which are not being added to Google Shopping, without any reason whatsoever. The products are all in stock, are visible in catalog and search and are active. They have also been added to the proper store and website and are assigned to a category. The module also throws no errors.

What would be the proper way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of Content API was introduced on June 6th 
http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/the-new-improved-content-api-for.html

along with 100s of changes while the last time Magento's Content API extension was updated (last update in 2012).
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html (See release notes)

Google is updating its eCommerce products so rapidly that keeping up to its speed will require a dedicated technical team to keep your store synced with Google (which owns 19% of the eCommerce transactions share in United States only)